# Oracle - how to update table column by subtracting a value in a subquery?

Tags: sql, oracle

this query gives an error on (-) on the trigger

```
UPDATE CHART_ACCOUNT
SET BALANCE=BALANCE-(SELECT SUM (AMOUNT) 
                     FROM CHASH_PAYMENT_DETIALS) 
WHERE CHART_ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_ID=CHASH_PAYMENT_DETIALS.ACCOUNT_ID
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As written, your question is vague. It's more of a statement than a question. And it doesn't include the error. Doesn't include what you're expecting the update to do. Please edit your question accordingly. (also, please be sure to properly tag your question; as originally tagged, nobody would have ever seen this as an Oracle pl/sql question)

Comment: Are you getting a mutating table error by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

```
UPDATE CHART_ACCOUNT ca
    SET BALANCE = BALANCE - (SELECT SUM(AMOUNT)
                             FROM CHASH_PAYMENT_DETIALS cpd
                             WHERE ca.ACCOUNT_ID = cpd.ACCOUNT_ID
                            )
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM CHASH_PAYMENT_DETIALS cpd
                  WHERE ca.ACCOUNT_ID = cpd.ACCOUNT_ID
                 );
```